# How to pass PHP variable (from loop process) to Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, while-loop

i have a while loop in my coding

```
while (($i < $num3b)&&($i < ($start+$perpage))) {
 $tododetail_id=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"tododetail_id");
 $comment=formatUrlsInText(mysql_result($result3b,$i,"comment"));
 $staff_name=mysql_result($result3b,$i,"staff_name");

 echo "<tr><td><span><font color='#5858FA'>" . $staff_name . nl2br($comment) . "</font>
 <span style='float:right' id='create-user'>Reply Message</span>";
$i++;}
```

How can onclick "Reply Message" jquery will popup `$staff_name` and `$comment` accordingly. 
This is my jquery code

```
    $( '[id^="create-user"]')
  .click(function() {
  var nameStf = $(this).data('id');
  alert (nameStf);
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: **id should always be unique** ...`id='create-user'`

Comment: Why are you using a `font` tag?

Comment: @bipen can i put $i in my id?but how can the jquery know my id?

Comment: `$( '[id^="create-user"]')` this is the root of all evil, and is an absolute abomination to jQuery performance.

Comment: @JezenThomas that's what i can think right now. that font will popup modal window in the same page of my coding.

Comment: you can use a class instead of an ID

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If so, you should mark one as ‘accepted’.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `data-attributes`

**HTML**

```
<span style='float:right' class="reply" data-staffname="staffname" data-comment="staff comment">Reply Message</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.reply').click(function() {
        var staffname = $(this).data('staffname');
        var comment = $(this).data('comment');
        alert(staffname + ': ' + comment);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is a mess, and your jQuery doesn’t correspond with it. You have this line:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
```

But you haven’t shown us any HTML that includes an element with the ID `dialog-form`.

You should restructure your HTML so you don’t use the `font` tag, every ID is unique, and tags are properly nested and closed. Run your output HTML through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) if you’re not sure.

Then, you can do something like this:

```
$('span').click(function(){
  alert($(this).closest('.comment'));
});
```

Obviously you’ll have to put the comment data in an element with the class `comment`.

Also, if you want to select an element by its ID with jQuery:

```
// Incorrect
$('[id^="create-user"]')

// Correct
var $createUser = $('#create-user');

// Also correct (normal JavaScript)
var createUser = document.getElementById('create-user');
```

Comment: thanks a lot..actually i'm really new in jquery. never used it before until last monday i have to worked with Modal Window.

Answer (score 0):

When you echo tags, I can't see you are closing them anywhere. Your HTML must be correct in order for jQuery to work properly. Also ID must be unique so use class.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span style="color: #5858FA;">SOMETHING 2</span>
        <span class="create-user">Reply Message</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$('.create-user').click(function(){
    var $text = $(this).prev().text();
    alert($text);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gjaBH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique give it as something like the id from the database. Then put the jquery script inside the loop. or else in the html use a onclick function which passes the id to the JavaScript function.

```
<?php
echo "<tr><td><span><font color='#5858FA'>" . $staff_name . nl2br($comment) . "</font>
 <span style='float:right' id="<?php echo $row['id'];">Reply Message</span>";
$i++;
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $( "#<?php echo $row['id']; ?>")
  .click(function() {
  var nameStf = $(this).data('id');
  alert (nameStf);
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
</script>
<?php }?>
```

Try not to use html inside an echo statement since echo is a php statement which loads from the server which is slower than normal html which loads in the browser.